# How do I show $\displaystyle\lim_{n\to\infty} \int_{0}^{1} \frac{1+(n/2)x}{(1+x)^{n/2}} \,dx = 0$?

Tags: real-analysis

I want to prove $\displaystyle\lim_{n\to\infty} \int_{0}^{1} \frac{1+(n/2)x}{(1+x)^{n/2}} \,dx = 0$.

I think a proof would work using something like the dominated convergence theorem.

Looking at the numerator makes me want to write $(1+x)^{n/2} = 1 + (n/2)x + \text{higher powers}$. We get $\frac{1+(n/2)x}{(1+x)^{n/2}} \le 1$. But this isn't a very useful upperbound.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using [Bernoulli's Inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bernoulli%27s_inequality), for $n \geq 2$,
$$f_{n}(x) = \frac{1 + (n/2)x}{(1 + x)^{n/2}} \leq \frac{(1 + x)^{n/2}}{(1 + x)^{n/2}} = 1$$
We also have that
$$f_{n}(x) = \frac{1 + (n/2)x}{(1 + x)^{n/2}} \to f(x) = \begin{cases} 1 & \text{for }x = 0 \\ 0 & \text{for } x \in (0,1] \end{cases}$$
pointwise. By the Dominated Convergence Theorem,
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\int_{0}^{1}f_{n}(x) \ dx = \int_{0}^{1}f(x) \ dx = 0$$

Comment: Why do we have this pointwise convergence?

Comment: I'm not OP, but the numerator grows linearly and the denominator grows exponentially, and therefore this follows from the fact that exponential growth dominates all polynomial growth. @LegNaiB

Comment: @AkivaWeinberger Don't bother. He is not making a genuine question. That comment is only a *spitting context*.

Answer (score 4):

For $1\geq x\geq 0$, $1+x\geq e^{x/2}$, and therefore $(1+x)^{-n/2}\leq e^{-nx/4}$.
Thus for $n\geq 1$, the integral $$0\leq\int_0^1 \frac{1+(n/2)x}{(1+x)^{n/2}}\mathrm{d} x \leq  \int_0^\infty (1+(n/2)x)e^{-nx/4}\mathrm d x= 12/n.$$ Clearly the upper bound converges to $0$.

Comment: Nice:  because both the original integrand and the approximation are $1 + x^2 (n^2 +O(n))/8 + O(x^3)$, the upper bound $4/n$ is tight.

Comment: The exponent should be $n/4$ instead of $n/2$. I edited the answer. I think the constant can be improved by starting with $1+x\geq e^{cx}$, where $c=\ln 2$.

Comment: Oh right:  starting with a correct inequality is important.  With $c = \ln 2$ you get a bound of $k/n$ where $k = 2(1+\ln 2)/(\ln 2)^2 \approx 7.05$.